# how can I get account information that connected by walletconnect?

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs, walletconnect

I linked my wallet with walletconnect using web3Modal.

How can I get the account information connected by walletconnect.

My program did not use react.

(I have binding account page and using account information page)